# Find which index in a multi level array throws undefined index error in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

So I have a nested php array which I am using using for fetching data:

`$this->synthArray[$synthId]['synth_map'][$mapId]['map_sequence'][$gnome];`

This line gives me error `undefined index` error sometimes.  I am trying to figure out which index gives that error - I can do `isset()` on each level to achieve this, but I was wondering if there is an easier way to find the culprit...

Comment: I can not give you any answer, because your question lacks imo a context. For instance, the first thing I would think of is query optimization. I see you have three variables in your array and two constants. Why those constants? And can they go wrong too? Too many questions that can not be answered with the information presented.

Comment: @LoekBergman - I do not think so. The context of my question is very clear. `A multi-level nested array throws an undefined index array. Is there an alternative to having to check each nested level to find the undefined index.` There is no need for more background information to answer that question (like why there are constants, query optimization etc - in fact I dont even know what query optimization has to do with anything), I am assuming you cannot give me an answer because you do not have one. Thank you for your reply though.

Comment: I can give you an answer concerning PHP and having only the array as part of the object to deal with: no, it is not possible. That is why I asked for the context to give an answer. Success!

Comment: @LoekBergman Not to get into a back and fro here - but needing to know the context is *totally irrelevant* to the question I asked. And a friend told me that I could array_walk in order to check this, so I think your answer is wrong as well...

Answer (score -2):

**Edit**
Your array has 3 points of failure...I mean there are 3 variables which can be absent in the array.

```
$this->synthArray[$synthId]['synth_map'][$mapId]['map_sequence'][$gnome];
```

You can check this as:

```
if(isset($this->synthArray[$synthId])) {
     if(isset($this->synthArray[$synthId]['synth_map'][$mapId])) {
         if(isset($this->synthArray[$synthId]['synth_map'][$mapId]['map_sequence'][$gnome])) {
             // it's correct
         } else {
             //$gnome is an invalid key
         }
     } else {
          // $mapId is an invalid key
     }
} else {
    // $synthId is an invalid key
}
```

You can use [set_error_handler](http://php.net/set-error-handler) to register your own error handler.

```
function errorHandler( $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    // catch the error here and take action
    echo "{$errstr} in file {$errfile} on line {$errline}"; // example

    /* Don't execute PHP internal error handler */
    return true;
}
set_error_handler('errorHandler');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do not see how this helps for what the OP is asking...the logging error will still only mention that there is an undefined index error in line X. It will not say which index is undefined

Comment: I know this does not show what key failed...just that it provided a way to catch the error and decide accordingly. Have updated my snippet for `if...else...if` to check the error. PHP does not provide any other way to detect the problem source afaik.